# Install JupyterHub on EKS fails: "No suitable subnet for ELB"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, subnet, jupyterhub, amazon-eks

I am experiencing an issue on my EKS cluster (kubernetes version 1.14).
I am trying to install JupyterHub (version 0.8.2) onto the EKS cluster, via helm+tiller.

Install appears to succeed, but the proxy-public service fails to create an ELB. See the output of "kubectl describe svc" below:

The app install/deployment fails with an error event.

```
> kubectl describe svc
...
Name:                     proxy-public
Namespace:                jhub
Labels:                   app=jupyterhub
                          chart=jupyterhub-0.8.2
                          component=proxy-public
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=jhub
...
  Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  1m (x6 over 3m)  service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service jhub/proxy-public: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

My EKS cluster is associated with 3 subnets, 2 private and 1 public. I would think that the ELB could be placed in the public subnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EKS requires subnets to be tagged in order to be used for load balancer creation. To be considered an eligible subnet, tag it with the following: `kubernetes.io/role/elb: shared`. For more info, see the [knowledge portal article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/) on subnet tagging for EKS.

Comment: Strange, I did not know about this and have never ran into this issue before. I was able to successfully install JupyterHub 0.8.2 on EKS 1.14 and ELB was created just fine. The only difference this time, is that I created all of the resources via terraform, whereas I used to provision the resources via cloudformation. What could be the reason I only ran into this issue and not before?

Comment: @JamesWierzba The cloudformation code probably tagged the subnets while the TF code did not

Comment: This worked, except the tag you mentioned was not the right one in my case, in my case I need to use `"kubernetes.io/cluster/eks_cluster_tf" : "shared"`

Comment: This happen to me on my second EKS cluster in the same VPC. First one up to 1.18 seem to be working without this. 1.19 onwards seems to need this.